# Convertir una lista Clave Valor a MultiLinea e inverso en Java

Tags: java

A partir de una lista `Map` con estructurada key,value

```
Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

map.put("param1","valor uno");
map.put("param2","valor dos");
map.put("param3","valor tres");
```

Para convertir una lista a cadena uso el método `toString`, para obtener los cojuntos de datos separados por lineas, remplazo algunos caracteres del retorno de la función `toString`

```
public static String mapToMultiLine(Map<String,String> map) {
  String str = map.toString().replace("{","").replace("}","").replace(", ","\n");
  return str;
}
```

Ahora me falta realizar la función inversa `multiLineToMap` , es decir que a partir de un cadena con una estructura

```
param1=valor uno
param2=valor dos

param3=valor tres
```

Se convierte a una lista key value (teniendo en cuenta que si hay una linea en blanco eliminarla.

**Update 1**, Tengo más o menos algo:

```
public static Map<String,String> multiLineToMap(String str ) {
    str = str.replaceAll("(?m)^[ \t]*\r?\n", ""); //eliminar lineas en blanco

    String lines[] = str.split("\n");

    //recorrer array lines
    //    separar key value, delimitador =
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba con algo semejante al siguiente fragmento:

```
// El mapa
Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

// El texto de entrada
String input = "a=1\n\t\nb=2\nc=3=3";

// Remover líneas en blanco
input = input.replaceAll("(\\r?\\n)([ \\t]*\\r?\\n)*", "$1");

// Utilizar la expresión regular (.*?)=(.*)
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(.*?)=(.*)").matcher(input);
while (matcher.find()) {
    map.put(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2));
}

// Opcionalmente comerte un pay ;-)
```

Comment: Gracias, funciona perfectamente

Answer (score 2):

Si alguien le interesa he adaptado el código de @Paul_Vargas a la función `multiLineToMap`

```
public static Map<String,String> multiLineToMap(String input  ) {

    Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    // Remover líneas en blanco
    input = input.replaceAll("(\\r?\\n)([ \\t]*\\r?\\n)*", "$1");

    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(.*?)=(.*)").matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        map.put(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2));
    }

    return map;
}
```

Testear la funciones:

```
    String test = "param1=valor uno\nparam2=valor dos\n\nparam3=valor tres";

    System.out.println(mapToMultiLine(multiLineToMap(test)));
```

La salida es la siguiente:

```
param1=valor uno
param2=valor dos
param3=valor tres
```